# CloudFront assets break when cache is stale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm having a problem with my CloudFront configuration. I'm not 100% sure that the following is true but it seems like the most likely scenario.

I have some assets being served on CloudFront. Let's say the URL is asdf.cloudfront.net/abc123.css.

When my CF cache is stale, CF falls back to my origin URL, mysite.com instead of asdf.cloudfront.net. So rather than asdf.cloudfront.net/abc123.css, CF tries to hit mysite.com/abc123.css. This is all as expected. So far so good.

The problem is that I don't just have one server at mysite.com, I have two servers behind a load balancer, and those two servers don't have the same asset digest. One server has assets at mysite.com/abc123.css and the other has assets at mysite.com/def456. So half the time, mysite.com/abc123.css is valid, and the other half the time, mysite.com/abc123.css gives a 404.

This must not be an uncommon problem. How do people typically deal with this? Is the typical solution to put your assets in S3 with `asset_sync` and use your S3 URL as the CF origin?

Comment: Are you precompiling at deploy time? Each server triggers a assets:precompile task? Why don't they have the same digest?

Comment: I have the same configuration, but my 4 servers have the same digests so no issues. I plan to change this in the future to precompile ahead. I don't sync with s3. Probably it's worth looking into why the digests are different.